# How can I create independently scrollable columns with Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get some fixed-height content at the top, with 2 columns below that are separately scrollable. I want them to take up whatever screen-height is available, so I can't use fixed `height` or `max-height`.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.5 so my markup looks like:

```
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>h1</h1>
                ...main nav...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-7">
                ...crumbtrail...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div id="col-left" class="col-7">
                ...left-content...
            </div>

            <div id="col-right" class="col-5">
                ...right-content...
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

It's those columns `col-left` and `col-right` that I want to scroll independently. I've tried 2 ways with flexbox and in both cases...nothing. No scrollbars. No visible difference at all.

Clearly I'm missing some basic bit of understanding here.

I'm not hung up on a flexbox solution. Some other CSS solution would be fine, or even JS if necessary.

---

### Way 1: flexbox on the top-level container

The idea is to make all the content flexible, but prevent the two header rows from shrinking. I'm going to do this all with Bootstrap 4 classes, so no `flex-basis`. But that's `automatic` by default which is what I want. I think.

Here's how I thought about it:

- `flex-grow-0` everywhere, because I don't want anything to grow to fill the space
- `flex-shrink-0` on the first two rows
- `flex-shrink-1` on the row containing my 2 columns, and on the columns themselves
- no flex css or classes on any of the stuff actually inside the columns

And as I said above, nothing happens.

```
<body>

    <div class="container d-flex flex-column">

        <div class="row flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>h1</h1>
                ...main nav...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
            <div class="col-7">
                ...crumbtrail...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="col-left" class="row flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-1">
            <div id="col-left" class="col-7 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-1">
                ...left-content...
            </div>

            <div id="col-right" class="col-5 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-1">
                ...right-content...
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

---

### Way 2: flexbox only on the row containing the two columns

Maybe flexbox on everything is overkill and that's messing things up? Let's try to be more focused.

- `d-flex` on the row containing my columns. This time it's `flex-row` instead of `flex-column`.
- I don't want the columns to grow or shrink on the main axis, so they're now `flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0`

Now I want my scrollbars on the cross-axis. `align-stretch` will stretch them on the cross-axis, but there's no `align-shrink`?

And that's where I get stuck.

```
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>h1</h1>
                ...main nav...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-7">
                ...crumbtrail...
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row d-flex flex-row">
            <div id="col-left" class="col-7 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                ...left-content...
            </div>

            <div id="col-right" class="col-5 flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0">
                ...right-content...
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You want the entire page not to exceed viewport height? You don't want the header at the top to scroll out of view?

Comment: I'm happy for the header to scroll out of view under some circumstances. The critical part is that left and right columns scroll independently. A JS event in one ultimately should scroll an element in the other into view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple solution. Flexbox is unnecessary. The columns need some CSS that I don't think is available as a Bootstrap utility class, so it involves a small amount of custom CSS.

Markup:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                ...main nav...
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-7">
                ...crumbtrail...
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="col-left" class="col-7">
                ...left-content...
        </div>

        <div id="col-right" class="col-5">
                ...right-content...
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div#col-left, div#col-right {
    max-height: 100vh;          /* not available in Bootstrap */
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This gives me the two independently scrollable columns within a page that is itself scrollable. They don't lose any available height to the header material or when I add footer material.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, the issue is a matter of `height` and `overflow`...

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column vh-100 mh-100 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="row flex-shrink-1">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>h1</h1> ...main nav...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-shrink-1">
        <div class="col-7"> ...crumbtrail... </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
        <div id="col-left" class="col-7 mh-100 overflow-auto"> 
          ...left-content...
        </div>
        <div id="col-right" class="col-5 mh-100 overflow-auto">
          ...right-content...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/B3qD9n4Vyy

Comment: That looks really promising. I'll take a look when I have a chance. Thanks Zim.

Comment: that's terrific. Thank you. There are some lessons for me there about managing heights and overflows, which is exactly what I was hoping for too.

Having had a play with it, I realise I'd assumed the page itself would still be scrollable. Sooner or later I'll have some footer content. With the solution as it stands, the footer will eat away at the bottom of the columns. Is it possible to scroll the page as well as the columns? Or is that a bit of a fantasy?

Comment: I've solved that. I'll post that below. WOuldn't have got there without your help @Zim – thanks!